# Is it possible to force PowerShell script to throw if a required parameter is omitted?

Tags: powershell

I would like the second function call in this script to throw an error:

```
function Deploy
{

param(

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$BuildName

    )
    Write-Host "Build name is: $BuildName"

}

Deploy "Build123"

Deploy #Currently prompts for input
```

Prompting is great for using the script interactively, but this will also be executed by our build server.

Is my best bet just doing some custom validation with an `if` or something?

Comment: Note that if you run powershell.exe with the `-NonInteractive` flag, missing mandatory parameters will cause an error and result in a non-zero exit code for the process.

Comment: Check out this Q&A where I posted a solution that doesn't involve manually invoking the PowerShell executable, using background jobs instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45935954/testing-for-mandatory-parameters-with-pester/62445526#62445526

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Once the parameter is marked as mandatory PowerShell will prompt for value. That said, if you remove the mandatory attribute then you can set a default value with a throw statement:

```
function Deploy
{
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$BuildName=$(throw "BuildName is mandatory, please provide a value.")
    )

    Write-Host "Build name is: $BuildName"
}
```

Comment: Strangely, for pipeline-bound parameters the default value is still evaluated which seems to make this technique unusable for throwing an error when a parameter is missing...at least if you're using pipeline parameters.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600279) discusses the unfortunate shortcomings of this workaround if you're using pipeline parameters.

Answer (score 36):

[@Emperor XLII](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2495/emperor-xlii) has a nice comment in the question that I think can be a better answer for some use cases:

> if you run `powershell.exe` with the `-NonInteractive` flag, missing
>   mandatory parameters will cause an error and result in a non-zero exit
>   code for the process.

The reasons to use this can be:

1. You have a lot of such `Mandatory=$true` parameters and the cost is high to convert all of them.
2. The script will be used both interactively and non-interactively, and when run interactively you do want to be prompted for missing parameters.